# Image Within Table Size Error, Safari Browser

Tags: css, image, safari, html-table

I generate a table of images within a div.

This works perfectly fine in mozilla and chrome, but not in safari:

This is what the output looks like sometimes in Safari, i.e. depending on a refresh:

[image: Normal Output]

As you can see the images are placed to the size of the td cells.

But sometimes when I refresh the page, this is what is generated:

[image: Wrong Output]

In my code I do a for loop over how many images are in my post.

Here is the code:

```
<table style="margin-top:2px; width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:center; padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <div class="blog-image" id="blog-image-419d6830569939e69a4e827a437af00b711b85cc" style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#8AAEA4;" data-keywords="">
                <a data-target="flare" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" data-flare-scale="fit">
                    <img style="display: block;" width="100%" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" alt="butterbean stew.jpg"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <div class="blog-image" id="blog-image-99c01d06fa65c7879df3f1db0520c98678af7577"  style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#8AAEA4;" data-keywords="">
            <a data-target="flare" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" data-flare-scale="fit">
                <img style="display: block;" width="100%" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" alt="welsh rarebit.jpg"/>
            </a>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <div class="blog-image" id="blog-image-c77d52058e55fc9dfa0520b9f786d8f5ff718074"  style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#8AAEA4;" data-keywords="">
                <a data-target="flare" href="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" data-flare-scale="fit">
                    <img style="display: block;" width="100%" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" alt="blackboard.jpg"/></a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <div class="blog-image" id="blog-image-"  style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#8AAEA4;"">
                    <img style="display: block;" width="46px" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">
            <div class="blog-image" id="blog-image-"  style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#8AAEA4;"">
                <img style="display: block;" width="46px" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02372/google-pipes-3_2372325k.jpg" alt="" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the relevant JS Fiddle, please note, that if you refresh the page in safari, it changes?! Weird!

[JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/naJ46/1/)

Can anyone tell my why the images are doing this? The solution to this would be to stop the images appearing small on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mess in your HTML. The main problem is that you are not setting the width of the table cells. A little fixed version using piece of CSS:

```
.thumbs td {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 25%; // <-- force td to be equal size
}
.thumbs td img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naJ46/2/

Advice: never use inline CSS in your HTML, this is extremely bad practice. In fact, one of the deadly sins.

Comment: thanks a lot, really helps, and yes I plan to stop doing inline css, i'm bad for it :D reputation++

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="blog-image" id="blog-image-"
  style="border-style:solid; border-width:1px; border-color:#8AAEA4;"">
```

Why is there no hash value(?) after `id="blog-image-` as is the case with the other occurrences? (This makes your code invalid because that id is used twice.)

And what’s with the `""` at the end of the `style` attribute value?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, on line 27 and line 32 you have doubled closing quotation marks. Second - you declare `width="100%"` for first two images, and `width="46px"` for third and fourth image, and that's the proper answer to your question, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, i removed the quotation marks it was to do with an if statement within my php